# Nikon d3300 better lens

Tags: lens

I have the Nikon d3300 and would like a better wide angle lens. Specifically for portrait photography. I'd like a nice blurred background as well. What do you suggest as the best and most affordable lens? Thank you.

Comment: generally wide-angle lenses are not well suited for portraiture. There is also "environmental portraiture", where you include the subject in some "environment", but even here a wide angle may not be appropriate.

Comment: Related: [Which focal-length lens is usually used for portrait photography, and why?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/916/which-focal-length-lens-is-usually-used-for-portrait-photography-and-why)

Comment: Better than what? What do you currently have that you are using for portraiture?

Comment: Hi Victoria. If there were a single answer to "best and most affordable", that lens would be the only one on the market. We generally don't do specific product recommendations on this site, and instead concentrate on making sure you're armed with the knowledge required to make your own decision.

Comment: Portraits of a single person? Portraits of 2-3 people? Of a handful of people? Of a group of 10-20? Of larger groups?

Comment: Related: [Why does the 55-250mm blur the background nicely and easily while the 18-55 does not?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82012/15871)

Comment: [What is a great portrait lens for Nikon (under $1000)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2362/15871)

Comment: [What is a portrait lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13636/15871)

Comment: [What lens is ideal for graduation and family pictures?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/71912/15871)

Answer (score 2):

A wide lens isn't usually suited for portraits as you have to get too close to the subject and it distorts the face.

I guess you already have the 18-55 kit lens. Maybe you have already seen that shooting at the widest is not the best for portraits.

I would suggest a 50mm 1.8 lens. It will provide you with blurred background. 50mm is maybe not regarded as a true portrait lens by some, because it is too short/wide but from my experience it is a rather versatile option for a beginner.

Comment: The typical advice regarding portrait lenses tends to be centered more around commercial concerns than artistic vision. See Weegee: https://www.icp.org/browse/archive/constituents/weegee?all/all/all/all/0 Assuming the 18-55mm lens suggests taking the desire for a wide angle at face value. I mean there's also Lomography...and used lenses.

Comment: I agree on the artistic vison part. I do not understand the "suggests taking the desire for a wide angle at face value" from your comment

Comment: If the author of the question has an 18-55mm lens, 'wide angle'  is closer to 18mm than 55mm. The suggestion of a 50mm f1.8 seems a bit like the answer to a different question (for example, "what lens would *you* use for portraits") than it is to the question that was actually asked. On a crop sensor the 50mm is narrower than a 'normal' lens.

Answer (score 1):

The Nikon D3300 is a compact digital. This camera’s image sensor measures approximately 16mm height by 24mm length. This format is called APS-C (Advanced Photo System – Classic). The focal length of lenses we fit to cameras is based on the format size.  First we compute the corner to corner measure of the format rectangle. This works out to 30mm (for your camera). This format, when fitted with a 30mm lens is said to deliver a “normal” view.  The term “normal” translates to an angle of view of 45° with the camera held in the horizontal position (landscape). Additionally the perspective delivered by such a lash-up is said to match the human experience --  thus the tag “normal”.

When we change lenses or zoom away from the 30mm “normal”, we can choose a shorter lens to gain a wide-angle view. Such a lens would be 70% of normal or shorter. This works out to 30 X 0.7 = 20mm or shorter. If we choose a focal length 2X “normal” we enter the realm of telephoto;  that’s 60mm or longer.

What I want you to know is, once you move away from 30mm, with this format, your images will yield a view that is not the normal perspective.  That’s OK because preserving a “normal” perspective is unimportant for the majority of pictures we make.  In fact, violating the “normal” perspective is often praiseworthy.  As an example, when doing portraiture, we benefit if the chosen focal length is a moderate telephoto.  The preferred focal length range is about 2X thru 2.5X of “normal”.  For your camera that’s 50mm thru 80mm.

Now, everything in photography has its reasons. The 2X thru 2.5X rule of thumb is based on how people perceive what they look like. Our view of ourselves comes from the makeup or dressing mirror. Things in the mirror appear to be behind the mirror, double the distance you are from the mirror. We use a moderate telephoto to duplicate this view.

The real point is, if you choose too short a focal length for portraiture the facial features will likely be distorted. The usual result is a slightly enlarged nose and petite ears. This distortion can be minuscule however they are a big deal when it comes to the human face. What I am saying is, use a moderate telephoto, this forces you to step back when doing portraiture and this mitigates facial distortion.

As to the buttery effect:  This comes about when the depth-of-field is shallow. A short lens has a vast depth-of-field, just what you don’t want. A long lens has a shallow depth-of-field and this is what you want. This dovetails into the rule of thumb I have describe.  Additionally, a lens with a large working aperture like f/1.4 or f/2 or f/2.8 delivers a shallow depth-of-field. One trick to achieve the buttery effect with a “normal” is to have the subject extend their hand a few inches forward of their face. You then focus on the hand by partially depressing the shutter button. Keep the button half depressed and then compose your subject. The focus point in front of the subject stays in place, until you complete the snap. This technique throws the background out-of-focus however the depth-of-field carries to keep the subject in focus. Try it, you’ll like it.